# How to define only selected foreign attributes in spring entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Supposedly I have two entities joined as such following:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName = "id") //Table user in database has foreign key role_id
    private Role role;

}

@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

How do I only create User entity with only one of role attributes instead of the whole? (for example, role name only)

I expect something like

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    // Some prefix or annotation maybe?
    private String role_name;

}
```

Comment: You can't. If your role name is unique, then you can use it as PK and map it as is in the `User` entity. Any other field that is not part of the `User` table (or some junction table), cannot be mapped in `User` table.

Comment: Even with the @Query or some kind of View (SQL) approach?

Comment: Well, you could use [DTO projections](https://vladmihalcea.com/dto-projection-jpa-query/). That way you could have an object with any field you like, but you won't be able to do any manipulations like on an `@Entity`.

Comment: I have read some of DTO approaches. Though it may resolve the problem, I suppose it will arise the N+1 problem

Comment: No, it won't. You only have 1 query and you map the result to a DTO. You are not iterating over lazily loaded `*ToMany` relation.

Comment: Ahhhh, Didn't think about that, I thought of the conversion from entity to DTO. Thank you!

Comment: Even in that situation, if you `join fetch` role (e.g. `select u from User u join fetch u.role where u.id = :id`), it would still be 1 query, and you could convert your entity (which contains all information) to a DTO.

Answer (score 0):

Like you read in the comments already, you will need a DTO approach for this and I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(User.class)
public interface UserDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getUsername();
    String getPassword();
    @Mapping("role.name")
    String getRoleName();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`UserDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, UserDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<UserDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!